# Python Mulit-Index: Changing second level of index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a general question about multi-column index. I want to change name second level of index (nm) to 'ns1' and 'ns2'. Take a look at my df below.

```
Out[13]: 
key  nm         0         1         2         3
bar abc -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    dse -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz cws  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    cwd -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo efw  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    vqx  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux zxe -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    res -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061

Out[13]: 
key  nm         0         1         2         3
bar ns1 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    ns2 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz ns1  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    ns2 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo ns1  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    ns2  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux ns1 -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    ns2 -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
```

Noticed that the second level of index name changed from all random strings to 'ns1' and 'ns2'. Is there a pythonic way to change this? My original dataframe is very big, so its hard to do manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and assign back:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], ['ns1','ns2']], 
                                      names=df.index.names)
print (df)
                0         1         2         3
key nm                                         
bar ns1 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    ns2 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz ns1  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    ns2 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo ns1  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    ns2  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux ns1 -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    ns2 -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
```

Similar solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], ['ns1','ns2']], 
                                              names=df.index.names))
print (df)
                0         1         2         3
key nm                                         
bar ns1 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
    ns2 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
baz ns1  0.404705  0.577046 -1.715002 -1.039268
    ns2 -0.370647 -1.157892 -1.344312  0.844885
foo ns1  1.075770 -0.109050  1.643563 -1.469388
    ns2  0.357021 -0.674600 -1.776904 -0.968914
qux ns1 -1.294524  0.413738  0.276662 -0.472035
    ns2 -0.013960 -0.362543 -0.006154 -0.923061
```